# OpenSUSE Xen installlation is not in Grub 2

Tags: xen, opensuse, grub2

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate but somehow serverfault search action didn't work with my browser.

I have a functional recent OpenSUSE Tumbleweed installation and I want to turn it into a hypervisor. I went to YaST, virtualisation, installed xen and xen-tools. It did even install a grub2-x86_64-xen package as I saw in package management. It has a working 20_linux_xen script in /etc/grub.d, but I don't see an entry in /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

#### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen

#### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen

Two commented lines are all I have. Could you post me a link to solution? I just cannot think of a correct configuration for xen will be as I booted only Linuxes before.

UPD: Here is a link to bugzilla thread https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=902521

I have switched to factory as was suggested in the above thread and reinstalled Xen along with distribution upgrade. Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

OK for everyone reading this, here is the asnwer: install a package named kernel-xen and do an `update-bootloader --refresh`